# http GET request from python echo server using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch

I have a Python echo server that sends a continuous stream of data when a client sends a GET request, as follows:

```
GET request for /?value=30
GET request for /?value=30
GET request for /?value=30
GET request for /?value=37
GET request for /?value=37
GET request for /?value=37
```

The snippet of the Python echo server, which uses the http.server library:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import logging


class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_response(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.info("GET request,\nPath: %s\nHeaders:\n%s\n", str(text), str(self.headers))
        self._set_response()
        self.wfile.write("get_value: GET request for {}".format(text).encode('utf-8'))
```

Node.js code that logged the data response above:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

function httpGet(theUrl) {
  let xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttpReq.open("GET", theUrl, false); 
  xmlHttpReq.send(null);
  return xmlHttpReq.responseText;
}
var i = 1
while (i ==1) {
  console.log(httpGet('http://localhost:8080'));
}
```

I have successfully retrieved the data using a Node.js code however I wasn't successful in implementing it in React. How should I write a simple GET/fetch request in React? I'm very new to React and thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetch-api to create HTTP request, here is react example:

```
componentDidMount() { 
   fetch('http://localhost:8080') 
     .then((res) => res.json()  {
      console.log(res)
      }) 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the heads up. Can you provide an example for this api until the html frontend? I tried using this but didnt seem to work. Thank you very much and it means a lot to me